# How do I reset all players spawn positions when joining?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have just created a Minecraft server to play with friends, but I would like to make sure that every time a player joins the server they spawn directly at spawn, instead of the last position they were in. Is there any way that I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Set up a command block chain with the following command:

/spawnpoint @a x y z

X, Y, and Z being coordinates of the spawnpoint.

Edit:

/setworldspawn will also work

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a bukkit based server *(bukkit, spigot, paper, etc)* you can use EssentialsX and EssentialsX spawn.
Then in `config.yml` you should go to

```
spawnpoint: <SPAWNPOINT NAME>

spawn-on-join: true
```

And in `spawns yml` you can manage your spawns.
In your permissions plugin *(I recommend luckperms)* you can then set spawnpoints and exceptions per-group or per-player.

I recommend reading the documentation of the plugins and watching a tutorial if you're new to plugins.

If not using a plugin supporting server, you're probably limited to commandblock trickery.